# Load Yaml file in Python without converting to dict

Tags: python, yaml, prometheus, etcd

I need to store the content of a yaml file to a variable as it is(without converting to dictionary) or after storing it as dictionary is there any way to bring back to yaml format without storing it inside the file. I tried with yaml.load(file) which returns the object in dictionary. 
Is there any way to achieve?

Comment: What about reading yaml as a text file?

Comment: If you don't want to parse it, it's nothing other than a plain text file, isn't it?

Comment: @Alderven Yes, if the yaml is valid i need to read it from .txt file. The question is how to store the yaml contents as it is.. without storing it into any files.!

Comment: What do you mean by 'to store as it is?'

Comment: @Taegyung I meant without converting to dictionary

Comment: Yeah so why don't you just read the file as plain text? Did you try what's suggested in the answer below?

Comment: Thank You, that worked but after reading the file when i print the variable for every line ^M character is appending .. How can I avoid it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about?

`ymlFile = open('file.yml').read()`

https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python

Comment: The recommended extension for YAML files has been `.yaml` since 2006 (as shown in the FAQ on yaml.org). What is your excuse for not following the recommendation?

Comment: @Terrillo after reading the file when i print the variable for every line ^M character is appending .. How can I avoid it?